# How to make mplayer or VLC start playing video at strict time?

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player, time, mplayer

I want mplayer and VLC start playing at exact time. Player should:

1. Load video file, buffer it, prepare everything;
2. Wait for UNIX time to be N seconds M milliseconds
3. Start playing according to framerate (without long-term deviations)

How it's better to attain this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a FIFO as input in MPlayer and start playback at the specified time.

I copy paste some minimal code examples I used in a script years ago that were used to skip in videos for scripting reasons.

1. Create a FIFO:

   ```
   [ ! -p /tmp/mplayer-fifo ] && mkfifo /tmp/mplayer-fifo
   ```
2. Start MPlayer with e.g.

   ```
   mplayer myfile.avi -input /tmp/mplayer-fifo
   ```
3. Send the skip command from another script with

   ```
   echo "seek 10" > /tmp/mplayer-fifo
   ```

You can instead use the FIFO to start and pause the video. Use `at` to run the play command at a specific time.

If the video is started and then immediately paused and then just waits for the `"play"` directive, then all buffering should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote my own alarm clock with at and a fifo. I had to set the seek value to `-9999` to get to the start of a song. However, I then used crontab and had to dismiss the earlier alarm clock version with at and a fifo.